# Is there a web admin interface to manage MS Exchanage 2010 / AD over the web?

Tags: active-directory, domain, exchange-2010

I run an AD domain with Exchanage 2010 for a small business. The Exchange server is authoritative for several domains that I host for clients.

Some of these clients have many email addresses for their domains that they want forwarded various places. Right now I manage the mail contact forwards manually on a request basis. However, clients keep asking me if they can manage the mail contact fowards themselves.

Is there any web admin tool that would allow me to provision a very basic management interface so that a domain user can log in and create/edit mail contacts for their domain? If so, what is the best tool for the scope of the task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you delegate distro list ownership to someone, I believe they can use the address book in Outlook to manage membership.  Not a web site, but most folks have it already on hand.

Other than that, Quest makes a self-service tool for AD as part of Active Roles server